# Error in eclipse helios whenever i try to install any plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

even when i try to install the required dependent error, another same typer error comes!
Pl give me so solution for this [screenshot of error type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ukpv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plug-in you're trying to install requires at least Indigo. Helios is too old.

Comment: indigo , means eclipse indigo?